# suppress the LDAP authentification for an application in NGINX

Tags: nginx, ldap, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I apply NginX to authenticate Applications for instance myapp1 and myapp2 with LDAP ([described here](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap)). My config file looks like:

```
ldap_server myapp1{
    url ldaps://....;
    binddn "CN=user,OU=t accounts,DC=dom,DC=uk";
    binddn_passwd ...;
    group_attribute member;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    max_down_retries_count 5;
    satisfy any;
    Require valid-user;
}
ldap_server myapp2{
    url ldaps://....;
    binddn "CN=user,OU=t accounts,DC=dom,DC=uk";
    binddn_passwd ...;
    group_attribute member;
    group_attribute_is_dn on;
    max_down_retries_count 5;
    satisfy any;
    Require valid-user;
}
```

It works well. Now, I want to supress the authentification for **myapp2** in other words, if a user calls the `url` adress for **myapp2** in the browser, the user will not be asked for the authentification and will come directly to the url, but just for **myapp2**.Is it possible?

**Update:** I figured out, that there is another part of `nginx.conf`, namely the proxy part:

```
    location /myapp1/ {
      auth_ldap_servers myapp1;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp1/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /myapp2/ {
      auth_ldap_servers myapp2;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp2/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

probably I have to change something in `location` part?

Comment: Try to drop `auth_ldap_servers myapp2;` from `location /myapp2/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found finally the solution.

the problem was, that tere is an aditional part in `nginx.conf` at the beginning. Thses should be integrated in the second part  `location /myapp/ { ....}`. Therefore from:

```
   auth_ldap "please log in with windows login data";
   auth_ldap_servers myapp1;
   auth_ldap_servers myapp2;
#comment:
# the special part for every app
    location /myapp1/ {
      auth_ldap_servers myapp1;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp1/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /myapp2/ {
      auth_ldap_servers myapp2;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp2/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

to

```
    location /myapp1/ {
      auth_ldap "please log in with windows login data";
      auth_ldap_servers myapp1;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp1/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /myapp2/ {
      auth_ldap "please log in with windows login data";
      auth_ldap_servers myapp2;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/myapp2/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```